# UIImagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: doesn't close UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

My application opens a `UIImagePickerController` like this

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I've implemented `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` in it I'm extracting the image making some  extrapolations and calling a service with post request sending data including the photo. according to the returning response I'd like to add a subview with a custom success/failure message.

**My Problem:** although my first line of code in this function is:

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

the picker doesn't close itself.

Comment: Can you post your code from `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`?

Comment: Try sending `dismiss` to `self` rather than to `picker`.

Comment: Perhaps you've forgotten to set the image picker controller's `delegate` to `self`, so the delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is never called. Show your actual presentation code.